# Create an array with counts of values from another array with the value as a key and the count as the value

Tags: php, arrays

I've just surveyed my seven friends about their favourite fruit (not!) and I want to provide the results in an array e.g.

```
Array ( [Apple] => 4 [Orange] => 1 [Strawberry] => 2 [Pear] => 0 ).
```

I've come up with a solution for this, but it seems in elegant. Is there a way of doing this within the 'foreach', rather than having to use the array combine. Thank you.

```
// Set the array of favourite fruit options.

$fruitlist = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Pear');

// Survey results from seven people
$favouritefruitlist = array('Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Apple','Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Strawberry');

// Create an array to count the number of favourites for each option
$fruitcount = [];
   foreach ($fruitlist as $favouritefruit) {
      $fruitcount[] = count(array_keys($favouritefruitlist, $favouritefruit));
    }

// Combine the keys and the values
$fruitcount = array_combine ($fruitlist, $fruitcount);

print_r($fruitcount);
```

Comment: `array_count_values` method should be helpful in this case.

Comment: I've actually found a simple way of editing the above so it works

1) Change it from ' $fruitcount[] = count' to '$fruitcount[$favouritefruit] = count'

2) Remove the array_combine bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you still want to use `foreach` instead of `array_count_values`, you should loop over `$fruitlist` first to build the keys, then over `$favouritefruitlist` to populate the array, as such :

```
<?php
// Set the array of favourite fruit options.
$fruitlist = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Strawberry', 'Pear');

// Survey results from seven people
$favouritefruitlist = array('Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Strawberry');

// Create an array to count the number of favourites for each option
$fruitcount = [];
foreach ($fruitlist as $fruit) {
    $fruitcount[$fruit] = 0;
}
foreach ($favouritefruitlist as $favouritefruit) {
    $fruitcount[$favouritefruit]++;
}

print_r($fruitcount);
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [Apple] => 4
    [Orange] => 1
    [Strawberry] => 2
    [Pear] => 0
)
```

(BTW, I can't believe none of your friends like pears...)

Answer (score 4):

Just try with [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

```
$fruitcount = array_count_values($favouritefruitlist);
```

To have also `0` values you, try:

```
$initial = array_fill_keys($fruitlist, 0);
$counts = array_count_values($favouritefruitlist);
$fruitcount = array_merge($initial, $counts);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The issue with this is that if a fruit has zero number of counts (e.g. pears) it is missing from the $fruitcount array, rather than saying 0